# Ubuntu 13.04 kernel panic after installing laptop-mode tools

Tags: 13.04, kernel, overheating

Since my laptop was overheating I first installed Jupiter. At that point there was no problem. But then I installed laptop-mode tools. Now the problem is every time I try to switch from battery to AC power or vice versa I am having kernel panic. After I removed the laptop-mode tools the problem is not there. But I really want to use the laptop-mode as it really helps to make my laptop a bit more cooler.

Any help is appreciated as I am not very aware of technicalities. Also there does not seem to be many such issues in 13.04 , at least I could not find it.

Comment: Please include the text of the Kernel Panic error. It should be on `/var/log/dmesg`. Please, copy and paste the last 30 lines.

Comment: I get the same thing.  @Braiam how do you get the dmesg log when a kernel panic happens?  My machine freezes when it happens and I must reboot.

Comment: Check this out http://askubuntu.com/q/82412/169736