# Installing 'wine' triggers a kernel panic, what can I do about this?

Tags: 13.04, kernel, wine

I was installing wine with the command `sudo aptitude install wine` and the computer crashed.

When I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, the computer crashes again.

What can I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by Computer Crashed? Could you explain little more! What was actual scenario? What error did you get? And what do you mean by Crashes Again? Is there any crashing loop of Ubuntu??

Comment: Define "crashed" or "crashes" in context.  Does the command just fail?  Is there a kernel panic?  Does your computer just completely and suddenly power off?  We need more details of what exactly happens.

Comment: That message is not complete, we only see "Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to" and we can't see anything else.  Can you also include a shot of the rest of the message since it's being cut off?

Comment: Something ugly must be happening in the background, because normally `aptitude` and `apt-get` don't try and kill init... o.O

Comment: @ThomasW. I have been running 13.04 for months now this only occurred when tried to install wine and now I can't update since `sudo dpkg --configure -a` causes the problem to re-occur

Comment: Can you post the text of the error before the kernel panic?

Comment: @user1974 How do I get that?

Comment: @dustin: best way is to remove `wine` completely and re-install it! if you are able to go to `Recovery Mode` it may help you.. Reply if you need some help..

Comment: @SauravKumar how can I remove wine?  I have tried but is tells me `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: @dustin: Give a try to my suggestion, since it was so long I preferred to write as an answer.. Reply if you need more help..

Comment: What happens if you just do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: @Mitch told to `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Try safe-booting and see whether the problem persists.

Comment: I would give a read to the kernel team help page provided in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/q/82412/169736).

Comment: What graphics driver are you using?  Also try updating the Kernel.  See my [Answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343640/how-to-upgrade-kernel-version-3-10-from-ubuntu-13-04/343660#343660).

Comment: @Mitch I cant update my graphics driver: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/345571/linux-graphics-utility-intel) post for reason why.

Answer (score 0):

**If nothing worked for you then you should give it a try!**

- When your system starts chose **Safe Mode** (*2nd option* in grub menu. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while boots if your system starts directly without `Grub Menu`).
- From the Menu just go to **Grub** option, it will give a message like **Updating grub will mount your system in read/write mode**. Just chose **yes** to mount your system in read/write mode. It will update your grub and will exit from **Grub** menu.
- chose **network** option it'll enable your network.(May take some time)
- Then chose **dpkg** menu from the list, chose **yes** for all.
- Finally chose **root** option and login. Execute following commands one after another:

  ```
  # apt-get autoremove
  # apt-get autoclean
  # apt-get -f install
  # dpkg-reconfigure -a (it would take some time)
  # apt-get update  
  # apt-get dist-upgrade (skip if don't want to upgrade)
  # apt-get upgrade (skip if you don't want to upgrade)
  ```

  Then finally execute following command to remove `Wine`

  ```
  # apt-get autoremove wine
  # apt-get --purge remove wine
  ```
- Reboot your system and check if your problem is solved or not.

  ```
  # reboot
  ```

Reply if something goes wrong.. or you need some help!

Comment: Nothing worked.

Comment: @dustin: It was just a suggestion to try.. If it doesn't work then I will delete it.. Just want your confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can solve the internal issues, but try downloading it the old fashioned way.

Go to `"Ubuntu Software Center"`, type wine in the search field and try downloading that way. See if that works...  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In order to isolate **hard disk issues**:

- Borrow a drive at least as large as the drive currently in your computer
- Boot from a live USB stick and [make a block level copy](http://dimitar.me/clone-disk-drives-with-ubuntu/) of your current drive to the borrowed drive
- Boot from the borrowed drive
- Retry

Let me know if you need more detailed instructions. If even cloning doesn't work, the reason is most probably a faulty drive.

Answer (score 0):

(Please, read the whole answer before doing anithing)

## Quick and Dirty (?)

Sometimes, when you don't know what to do, the best thing is start from 0. Use a Live system, do a full backup of all your data in the `/home` directory, if your system boots you can do `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall >> package.list` and save the resultant file, then reinstall the system.

When you get your new system, do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` once that is done restore your installed packages list.

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < package.list
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt-get deselect-upgrade
```

Now, you got your system ready to rumble.

## I want to fix it without reinstall

This is tricky, and you will need to spend your time in this. You may need to read the [debugging the kernel guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProcedures), and/or throw a stab in the air with the follow procedure:

Since you said that the problem started with wine, I will assume the package is somehow dirty, or something is terribly wrong. So, instead "executing" lets say that we simulate:

```
sudo dpkg --no-act --configure -a
```

If the below command produce the Kernel Panic, is safe to assume that the scripts were incorrectly unpacked or that the package is incomplete. To discard first, you may use the Recovery Mode to run a filesystem check:

- When your system starts chose **Safe Mode** (*2nd option* in grub menu. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while boots if your system starts directly without `Grub Menu`).
- From the Menu just go to **Grub** option, it will give a message like **Updating grub will mount your system in read/write mode**. Don't chose **yes** to mount your system in read/write mode.
- Once you get the recovery menu, select check filesystem or `fsck`. It will take a time, repair the errors you find (if any), reboot into a normal boot, and try to run `sudo dpkg --no-act --configure -a` again. If no panic arises just run without the `--no-act` switch. It should work.