# How to upgrade Kernel Version 3.10 from Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, kernel

I want to upgrade Kernel. Now my linux kernel is 3.8.0-19-generic. How to upgrade my kernel?

i am linux beginner.

Answer (score 2):

To Install / Upgrade Kernel 3.10.10, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

For 32bit

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.10.10-saucy/linux-headers-3.10.10-031010-generic_3.10.10-031010.201308291422_i386.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.10.10-saucy/linux-headers-3.10.10-031010_3.10.10-031010.201308291422_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.10.10-saucy/linux-image-3.10.10-031010-generic_3.10.10-031010.201308291422_i386.deb
```

For 64bit

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.10.10-saucy/linux-headers-3.10.10-031010-generic_3.10.10-031010.201308291422_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.10.10-saucy/linux-headers-3.10.10-031010_3.10.10-031010.201308291422_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.10.10-saucy/linux-image-3.10.10-031010-generic_3.10.10-031010.201308291422_amd64.deb
```

Once done then run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.10.10-*.deb linux-image-3.10.10*.deb
```

<sup>Source:[Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/linux-kernel-3-10-10-released-install-upgrade-in-ubuntu-13-04/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here are generic instructions that work on any version:

There's a lag between when a Kernel is released, and when it's available packaged in  Ubuntu updates.  If you need to run a current Kernel to test a bug fix or for some other reason, you'll have to download it yourself from:

```
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
```

You'll need to match your Ubuntu version, and your 32 or 64 bit system type.
Download those files to your `/tmp` partition using `wget` or something similar, and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb
```

Optionally, to remove an old Kernel, find it's version number then run:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-YYYYYY*
```