# linux graphics utility intel

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics

The linux graphics utility from intel say it doesn't support 12.04.  Since 13.04 is only supported for 9 months and 12.04 is LTS, why would 12.04 be considered obsolete and not receive support?

Or is there a way around this?

Edit:

Even using the 64bit version of intels 1.0.1 utility, I am told my distro isn't supported.  It is hard to call 12.04 LTS if 3rd party hardware manufacturers call it obsolete.

Comment: So what's the problem, you have to install the dependency packages. Best way to install it using `Synaptic Package Manager`. I recommend you to start installing from bottom to top as listed from your list. One more thing, I'm also using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and managed to install `Intel-Linux-Graphics-Installer 1.0.1` using `Synaptic`, but it never works for me.. :) It always says `Distribution not supported` ;) Hope it works for you..

Comment: I've installed this about a month ago, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Mitch it may.  Intel may have cut off all support sometime between now and then.  They could have had that server up still or latent support still.

Comment: @Mitch: I tried this on `Ubuntu 12.04.2`, just after Ubuntu `12.04.2` release. May be you tried it on `Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.04.1`. I was also able to install it but it never works, it fails in `checking distribution`. :(

Comment: Are you running 32bit or 64bit Ubuntu?

Comment: Then you need to download this [file](http://ubuntuone.com/0Oasf9aomdTWcAr41SXvUk) the 64bit.  My mistake, I should've asked before.

Comment: I'll research more, and get back to you.

Comment: @dustin: One word to you: It's not always that installing `Intel-Linux-Graphics-Installer` would fix your problem. I've seen many cases where it makes the situation more worst.. I would like to ask you what is your problem related to graphics? If you're facing such problem you can ask it? We will give our best to solve them!!

Comment: @SauravKumar it isn't a major problem.  The card is recognized.  I am pretty sure it is the utility or nothing to solve it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Intel Linux graphics installer 1.0.1 [here](http://ubuntuone.com/2X1R6qw7TjCsTyC6mPF7uV), and try it.

Support for Ubuntu 12.04 effectively ended when the Intel Linux Graphics Installer version 1.0.1 was released (20 May 2013), hence 12.04 would be considered obsolete (as far as the Intel Linux graphics installer.<sup>Intel</sup>

Comment: I've used it on a freshly installed 12.04 fully updated, and it installed without any problems, or dependency problems.  Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt get upgrade` before installing.

Comment: Well I tried.  Sorry it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add oibaf ppa for latest Intel drivers for 12.04

Comment: could you please extend your answer adding some more info.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver?field.series_filter=precise oibaf has removed support for 12.04 but Glassen has it, add the ppa and you will be updated to relatively newer version of Intel driver.